# Does android studio apps collect user data by default? is there any way to see what type of data is exported?

Tags: android, mobile, privacy, privacy-policy

i'm making a simple android app with android studio and I have a few questions about the privacy policy that I need to write to publish in the PlayStore.

1. Do android studio apps collect any type of data *(by default)* that I need to implement in my privacy policy?
2. Does [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) collect any type of data that I need to implement in my privacy policy?
3. Is there a program or something else that let you see what type of user data is being exported by the app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

they take permissions to run there apps like they use location access and contact access browser access to get your search data

if of you internet and off location and all permission then they don't get your data .

Comment: So do i need to implement it in my privacy policy?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).